# IAP test user has unknown error

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm test IAP:

1) create a test user
2) run the app in simulator
3) pop the iap dialogue, saying it's in sandbox
4) choose use existing account, enter the test user

But it says "An unknown error has occurred", why?

plus, I cannot test app on a device. It's never in sandbox environment. Is it because the app has been released to AppStore? I want to add new iaps, how can I back to sandbox environment on device?

Comment: IAP do not work on the simulator, you have to test in a device

Answer (score 0):

For In-App purchase, always use a device (never the simulator). To do this, go to your app store settings (via the settings app) and log out any real user that might be logged in. After that, make your test-purchase and enter the test user credentials.

Comment: Can test in simulator? But only simulator says "sand-box", the device don't and cannot use test user account either. How to make "sand-box" on device?

Comment: You don't have to make any "sand-box", it's important that your application on iTunes is properly configured and that you use the correct bundle ids for each IAP. Other than that, it should work on a standard device.

Comment: Still don't know how. The iaps had already tested and approved before, and now I'm adding new iaps. The old ones failed with test users too.

Comment: When you say they failed - do you mean they failed on a device? Did the popup show up?

Comment: on device: a popup says the account has never been used (if use test account). in simulator: a description says "An unknown error occurred"

Comment: This could mean you've accidentally attempted to use this test user to perform a non-test action (such as purchase an app). Try creating a new test account and test it out of the box.

Comment: No, that never happens. The test user account is fresh. Is it because the app has already in AppStore? If the app has never been released in AppStore, it's in sandbox environment. But now it's in AppStore and I want to add new iaps, how can I back to sandbox environment again?